# "ERROR: Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension" while sudo gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu

I am getting through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
I have already completed most of the initial setup and I am stuck on the last part of installing rails.

Ruby version is

> ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

When I run the

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I get the following output

```
redd@tanya:~$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.8/ext/nio4r
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20211210-14142-ms6vi8.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.7
    --with-unistd-dir
    --without-unistd-dir
    --with-unistd-include
    --without-unistd-include=${unistd-dir}/include
    --with-unistd-lib
    --without-unistd-lib=${unistd-dir}/lib
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:471:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:613:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1124:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:971:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:970:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1123:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/nio4r-2.5.8/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/nio4r-2.5.8/gem_make.out
```

I have already tried all the fixes mentioned here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikIOpRnO1x4

I would appreciate any help in sorting out this problem. Also, if you know the process of finding the solution please mention that too. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You shouldn't normally install gems like rails as sudo. Do you have the same problem without sudo?

Comment: @SuneNilausen When I try gem install rails without sudo.

I get "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
   You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.7.0 directory."

Comment: Install build-essentials and try again. Moreover share OS details when asking about installation-related problems. Things are different for Debian, Mac, M1 mac, etc.

Comment: @FaizaanKhan Thank you so much. Your solution worked. My OS is Ubuntu version 20.4 btw. Will make sure to include OS details next time.

Answer (score 0):

install build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and try again it

```
sudo gem install rails
```